# C# vs VB.NET bitwise OR

Tags: c#, vb.net

Why does the OR operator in vb and C# give different results.

```
Console.WriteLine(0x2 | 0x80000000); output 2147483650
```

http://dotnetfiddle.net/wC9AgG

```
Console.WriteLine(&H2 Or &H80000000) output -2147483646
```

http://dotnetfiddle.net/g4tLQ9

Comment: These are the same 32 bit value. C# uses an unsigned integer `UInt32`, VB.net a signed integer `Int32`.

Comment: It's overflow/signed, not different OR results. Try `1 OR 2` vs. `1 |2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In VB.NET, `&H80000000` has type `Int32` and is a negative number. In C#, `0x80000000` has type `UInt32` and is a positive number. The difference between languages is not in bitwise OR, but in integer literals.

Most likely, the reason why the types are different is because C# evolved from a language that supported unsigned types, and VB.NET evolved from a language that did not. In a language without unsigned types, it made sense for `&H80000000` to be a negative integer.